# How to change shape from pointing to top to point to right

Tags: css

I want to change the shape of the CSS from pointing to top to point to right. This is what I have now:

[image: Shape that i get]

And this is what I want to have:

[image: Shape that i want]

This is my current CSS:

```
.base {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 55px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 55px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}
.base: before {
    border-bottom: 35px solid red;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -35px;
    width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler nowadays to use the CSS clip path facility rather than have to use borders and pseudo elements.

Clip path let’s you define a polygon in terms of percentages which means it is good for responsiveness, altering automatically to fit the dimensions of the element.

Here’s an example. Change the % values to suit the look you want.

```css
.shape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Caveat: not supported in IE

Answer (score 0):

Please with below CSS

```
.base{
      background: red;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 60px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-top: 55px;
      position: relative;
      width: 100px;
    }
    .base:before {
      border-left: 30px solid red;
      border-top: 30px solid transparent;
      border-bottom:30px solid transparent;
      content: "";
      height: 0;
      left:100%;
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      width: 0;
    }
```